# Ordering US in a Rally query result by iteration end date

Tags: rally

I need to write a query to extract from Rally the user stories (HierarchicalRequirement) with a given value for a custom field and release name, ordering them by their iteration end-date first and user story rank as second parameter, in a Java application.

I can write the working query itself, but  the order condition on the iteration end date doesnt work *the condition on the rank is straightforward: "Rank desc")

To order by iteration end date I passed to the "order" parameter of the SOAP API the string "Iteration.EndDate desc" but it doesnt work.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with SOAP but with the REST api it is straightforward:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api

```
 RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), 
    "user@company.com", "password");

 QueryRequest stories = new QueryRequest("hierarchicalrequirement");
 stories.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "ScheduleState"));
 stories.setOrder("Iteration.EndDate DESC,Rank DESC");

 QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(stories);
 if (queryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
     for (JsonElement result : queryResponse.getResults()) {
         JsonObject story = result.getAsJsonObject();
         System.out.println(String.format("\t%s - %s: ScheduleState=%s",
             story.get("FormattedID").getAsString(),
             story.get("Name").getAsString(),
             story.get("ScheduleState").getAsString()));
     }
 }
```

Comment: yes, the problem is on the order condition. 

"Iteration.EndDate DESC,Rank DESC" doesnt work! "Rank DESC" works, but not the section "Iteration.EndDate DESC"

Comment: Apparently from the WSAPI you can't sort on subfields such as Iteration.EndDate.  Instead you'll have to query for iterations by end date and then for each of those query for stories in that iteration ordered by rank.  We still recommend using REST over SOAP :-)